# Ruby / Rails - NoMethodError in Pages#home - Partial View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, model-view-controller, methods, variable-assignment

**Error:**
*NoMethodError in Pages#home (emphasized text undefined method `profile' for nil:NilClass*)

[image]

---

**Controller:** *pages_controller.rb*

```
    class PagesController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!, except:  [:landing, :home, :plan]

def home
    @contributor_plan = Plan.find(1)
    @elitecontributor_plan = Plan.find(2)
    @technician_plan = Plan.find(3)
    @elitetechnician_plan = Plan.find(4)
    @center_plan = Plan.find(5)
    @elitecenter_plan = Plan.find(6)
    @affair_plan = Plan.find(7)
    @eliteaffair_plan = Plan.find(8)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `@user` is `nil` and you can't call the `profile` method on a `nil` object.

If you look closely, your `before_filter`

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, except:  [:landing, :home, :plan]
```

is not calling `authenticate_user!` method for `home` action(specified in `except`). So, you don't really have access to the currently loggedin user.

So, you have to authenticate a user for the `home` action. Modify your `before_filter` to

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, except:  [:landing, :plan]
```

Also, devise exposes a method called `current_user` with which you can find the currently logged-in user. So, your view should use `current_user` and not `@user`.

```
<%= image_tag current_user.profile.avatar.url %>
```

Comment: I have revised the before_filter. Thank you. However, the error message remains. I assume I am not properly defining "user" in the pages_controller. Would this be correct?

Comment: @NathanielRand Updated my answer. Have a look and let me know if it solves the issue.

Comment: The problem has been resolved. Your contribution is valued. So Devise's "current_user" can be applied to any "authenticate_user!" page?

Comment: @NathanielRand As long as you have called `authenticate_user!` method in the controller actions, you can use `current_user` in the views.